# Exclude all other resources from subdomain in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I have a Rails 4.0 app with that allows users to access blogs through subdomains. My routes currently look like this:

```
match '', to: 'blogs#show', via: [:get, :post], constraints: lambda { |r| r.subdomain.present? && r.subdomain != 'www' }

resources :foobars
```

Now, when I navigate to `somesubdomain.example.com` I am indeed taken to the `show`action of the `blogs` controller action, as expected.

When I navigate to `example.com/foobars` I can access the `index` action of the `foobars` controller, as expected.

However, I only get a behavior I do not desire:
When I navigate to `somesubdomain.example.com/foobars`, I can still access the the `index` action of `foobars` controller.

Is there a way to limit or exclude *all* resources that I do not specifically allow for a particular subdomain (i.e. `somesubdomain.example.com/foobars` will not work unless otherwise specified).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to define a specific subdomain to **exclude** from a set of routes you can simply do this (uses negative lookahead regex):

```
  # exclude all subdomains with 'www'
  constrain :subdomain => /^(?!www)(\w+)/ do
    root to: 'session#new' 
    resources :foobars
  end
```

Or similarly, to define a specific subdomain to **include** a set of routes you could do this:

```
  # only for subdomain matching 'somesubdomain'
  constrain :subdomain => /^somesubdomain/ do
    root to: 'blog#show' 
    resources :foobars
  end
```

Another approach would be to define the constraint match in a class (or module) and then wrap all routes within `constraints` block:

```
class WorldWideWebSubdomainConstraint
  def self.matches?(request)
    request.subdomain.present? && request.subdomain != 'www'
  end
end

App::Application.routes.draw do

  # All "www" requests handled here
  constraints(WorldWideWebSubdomainConstraint.new) do
    root to: 'session#new' 
    resources :foobars
  end

  # All non "www" requests handled here
  root to: 'blogs#show', via: [:get, :post]

end
```

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I ended up doing.